# create global variable iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have several nib files and I need to track how many times the user clicks on buttons. Inside the method I would obviously include something like `counter++;` assuming counter is an int variable. But my problem is that I don't know where to define that variable so that all my nib files can have access to it.

What I have tried was to define the int variable counter in the  AppDelegate.h and .m files but I have not been able to access that variable within other .m files.

Or maybe I have to create it on the main.m file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two choices:

1. Use the AppDelegate. For other classes to access the AppDelegate, you need to `#import` it. For these classes to access variables and methods in the AppDelegate, they must be declared in its header file (.h).
2. Use a singleton. Classes access a "shared" class and have access to that shared class's variables and methods. See http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/ for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In general, global state is considered [bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

To access your app delegate is easy:

```
MyAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: They may be bad in some situations, but sometimes their usage is inevitable. It also depends on the language you are using.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'inevitable', more likely 'the easy way out'.  Once you fall into that hole, it's very hard/painful to get out of it.  I'm no saint in this area, I take the easy way allot...  But, these types of habits 'bite us in the ass' sooner or later.